# Access the ROOT detailViewController from the masterVewController in a splitviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

Here is the layout of my app

[image]

I am trying to access a variable of startViewController from within TableViewController.

When I print the viewControllers of splitViewController (`print(self.splitViewController?.viewControllers)`) from within tableViewController this is what I get

```
Optional([<UINavigationController: 0x12200f600>, <temp.CollectionViewController: 0x121e16860>])
```

That second viewController(`temp.CollectionViewController`) should be of type startViewController.

The startViewController in my program presents the collectionViewController using a segue with kind show. The collectionViewController has already been segued to when I call `print(self.splitViewController?.viewControllers)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up needing to put StartViewController inside a UINavigationController. I was then able to access the first viewController with

```
var detailStart = (splitViewController?.viewControllers[1] as? UINavigationController)?.viewControllers.first as? StartViewController
```

I then hid the unwanted navigation bar with

```
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
```

Which was placed inside viewDidAppear

---

This ended up being an ok solution for me, because I needed to put CollectionViewController inside a UINavigationController anyway, but it seems kind of hacky and maybe not the best practice

Answer (score 0):

try to cast it as below :

```
splitViewController?.viewControllers.forEach({ (vc) in
  if let startController = vc as? startViewController {
    --- Your code ---
    return
  }            
})
```